# cannot connect to my c++ server with public address

Tags: c++, client, winsock

I created a server and a client application in c++ (using winsock). When I start the server I can connect to it with the client using 127.0.0.1 address (when on the same computer obvviously) I can also connect to it when I use my hamachi network address (also from another computer which is the same hamachi network). The problem is when I try to use my public ip address, then I cannot connect to it from any computer. I have also my firewall turned off but it didnt helped.

Comment: Are you behind a NAT router? Does it have port forwarding enabled to your IP?

Comment: Routers need to know which of its clients are expecting connections on which ports, otherwise it would need to probe all its clients for the first open port as a hub might!  If you are using a router you will need to tell it that incomming requests for port X should be directed to machine Y.Y.Y.Y

Comment: I dont if Im behind NAT router, but it seems that port forwarding is not enabled, since I have tried some online testers and they say to all the ports I tried that theyre closed